# ASP.NET Core MVC Web App does not append slash before Id

Tags: c#, url, controller, asp.net-core-mvc, trailing-slash

I am watching some tutorials to learn ASP.NET Core.I'm creating a MVC Web App.In website i have edit option for products.When i click edit button it goes to this url ;

"https://localhost:5001/Admin/Products/Edit1"

and it gives me error.Instead it should go to

"https://localhost:5001/Admin/Products/Edit/1"

But it does not.How can i fix this ?

Product/Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<NewGraniteHouse.Models.Products>
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<br /><br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-info">Product List</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp; New Product</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br />
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped border">
        <tr class="table-info">
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Available)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ProductTypes)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SpecialTags)
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Available)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ProductTypes.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.SpecialTags.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <partial name="_TableButtonPartial" model="item.Id" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Product/Edit.cshtml

```
@model NewGraniteHouse.Models.ViewModel.ProductsViewModel
@using NewGraniteHouse.Extensions
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<br />
<h2 class="text-info">Edit Product</h2>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="p-4 border rounded row">
        <input hidden asp-for="Products.Id" />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="Products.Name"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input asp-for="Products.Name" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Products.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="Products.Price"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input asp-for="Products.Price" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Products.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="Products.Image"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input type="file" name="files" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="ProductTypes"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <select asp-for="@Model.Products.ProductTypeId" asp-items="Model.ProductTypes.ToSelectListItem(Model.Products.ProductTypeId)"
                        class="form-control"></select>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="SpecialTags"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <select asp-for="@Model.Products.SpecialTagsId" asp-items="Model.SpecialTags.ToSelectListItem(Model.Products.SpecialTagsId)"
                        class="form-control"></select>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="Products.ShadeColor"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input asp-for="Products.ShadeColor" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Products.ShadeColor" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="Products.Available"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Products.Available" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">

        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <img src="@Model.Products.Image" width="100%" style="border-radius:5px; border:1px solid #bbb9b9; " />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" />
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success">Back to List</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
@{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

_TableButtonPartial.cshtml

```
@model int
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@

<td style="width:150px">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" ">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Edit"+Model)">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Details"+Model)">
            <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i>
        </a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="@Url.Action("Delete"+Model)">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Edit : Added cshtml files.

Comment: Added.I tried changing "href="@Url.Action("Edit"+Model)" to "href="@Url.Action("Edit/"+Model)" but it goes to "https://localhost:5001/Admin/Products/Edit%2F1" it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your partial view it seems you have to pass `Id` as paramter to your controller method but you write it as

```
@Url.Action("Edit"+Model)
```

But best method overload for your requirement is the `@Url.Action(string actionName, object routeValues)`;

So now your action link will be modify and it look like.

```
@Url.Action("Edit", new {id = Model})
```

Now your partial view look like

```html
@model int
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@

<td style="width:150px">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" ">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = Model})">
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
        </a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = Model})">
            <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i>
        </a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = Model})">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Try this may it help you.